# How do I change the image being displayed when the user clicks on a "forward" or "backward" button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3" id="img1">
                <img src="Aliens.jpg" class="imgclass">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="img2">
                <img src="Ayrton%20Senna.jpg" class="imgclass">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="img3">
                <img src="le%20Ferrari.jpg" class="imgclass">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="img4">
                <img src="Batman%20and%20bats.jpg" class="imgclass">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button id="back">&larr;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <img src="Aliens.jpg"  class="bigimg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button id="fwd">&rarr;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
        $(".imgclass").click(function(){$(".bigimg").attr("src",$(this).attr("src"))});
        var d=1;
        $("img"+d).click();
        $("#back").click(function(){d=d-1; if(d<1){d=4;} $("#img"+d).click()});
        $("#fwd").click(function(){d=d+1; if(d>4){d=1;} $("#img"+d).click()});
    </script>
```

I have 4 images with ids img1 to img4. I have put two buttons with ids "fwd" and "back". When the user clicks on the fwd button, if img3 was being showed, now it should show img4. If he clicks on it again, img1 should be shown. Similar working was what I wanted with the back button too. The .imgclass is the class given to all of these images (img1, img2, img3, img4) and the .bigimg is where these images should be shown. However this code isnt working! Clicking on the two buttons does nothing. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: Share your HTML as well;

Comment: There are many already implemented carousels such as http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Use console.logs in all the JS functions to see where it breaks. Either the click on `#back` and `#fwd` doesn't work or it's the programmatically fired click on those elements. maybe it all stops even before, because you have some element title typos.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I have added the HTML as well.

Comment: He is running the code after the html is loaded so no need for document ready

Comment: Its only the buttons that are not working, the rest of the code is running as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

Here you are binding click event with `.imgclass` and when you are doing this `$("#img" + d).click();` this is a div element not the image so updated selector and in this selector you made one more mistake forgot to prepend `#`;

```js
$(".imgclass").click(function() {
  $(".bigimg").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});

var d = 1;
$("#img" + d + " .imgclass").click();

$("#back").click(function() {
  d = d - 1;
  if (d < 1) {
    d = 4;
  }
  $("#img" + d + " .imgclass").click()
});

$("#fwd").click(function() {
  d = d + 1;
  if (d > 4) {
    d = 1;
  }
  $("#img" + d + " .imgclass").click()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img1">
      <img src="Aliens.jpg" class="imgclass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img2">
      <img src="Ayrton%20Senna.jpg" class="imgclass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img3">
      <img src="le%20Ferrari.jpg" class="imgclass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img4">
      <img src="Batman%20and%20bats.jpg" class="imgclass">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button id="back">&larr;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <img src="Aliens.jpg" class="bigimg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button id="fwd">&rarr;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```js
$(".imgclass").click(function() {
  $(".bigimg").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});

var d = 1;
$("#img" + d + " .imgclass").click();

$("#back").click(function() {
  d = d - 1;
  if (d < 1) {
    d = 4;
  }
  $("#img" + d + " .imgclass").click()
});

$("#fwd").click(function() {
  d = d + 1;
  if (d > 4) {
    d = 1;
  }
  $("#img" + d + " .imgclass").click()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150 " class="imgclass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100 " class="imgclass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200 " class="imgclass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150 " class="imgclass">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button id="back">&larr;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <img src="Aliens.jpg" class="bigimg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button id="fwd">&rarr;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay..it worked when i wrote " .imgclass" and not ".imgclass" . What does the space do (between " and .imgclass ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your code in a ready block:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".imgclass").click(function() { 
        $(".bigimg").attr("src",$(this).attr("src"))
    });

    var d=1;
    $("img"+d).click();
    $("#back").click(function(){
      d=d-1;
      if(d<1){
        d=4;
      }
      $("#img"+d).click()
    });
    $("#fwd").click(function(){
      d=d+1;
      if(d>4){
        d=1;
      }
      $("#img"+d).click()
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 activePic" id="img1">
                <img src="Aliens.jpg" class="imgclass">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="img2">
                <img src="Ayrton%20Senna.jpg" class="imgclass">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="img3">
                <img src="le%20Ferrari.jpg" class="imgclass">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" id="img4">
                <img src="Batman%20and%20bats.jpg" class="imgclass">
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button id="back">&larr;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="mainImg col-md-10">
                <img src="Aliens.jpg"  class="bigimg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button id="fwd">&rarr;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    $('#back').click(function(){
      prev = $('.activePic').prev();
      if($('.activePic').is('[id^="img"]:first')) {
           prev = $('[id^="img"]:last');
      }
     $('.activePic').removeClass('activePic');
    prev.addClass('activePic');
    $('.mainImg img').attr('src',prev.find('img').attr('src'));
    });

    $('#fwd').click(function(){
      next = $('.activePic').next();
      if($('.activePic').is('[id^="img"]:last')) {
           next= $('[id^="img"]:first');
      }
     $('.activePic').removeClass('activePic');
    next.addClass('activePic');
    $('.mainImg img').attr('src',next.find('img').attr('src'));
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bbkyebcw/

```js
$('#back').click(function() {
  prev = $('.activePic').prev();
  if ($('.activePic').is('[id^="img"]:first')) {
    prev = $('[id^="img"]:last');
  }
  $('.activePic').removeClass('activePic');
  prev.addClass('activePic');
  $('.mainImg img').attr('src', prev.find('img').attr('src'));
});

$('#fwd').click(function() {
  next = $('.activePic').next();
  if ($('.activePic').is('[id^="img"]:last')) {
    next = $('[id^="img"]:first');
  }
  $('.activePic').removeClass('activePic');
  next.addClass('activePic');
  $('.mainImg img').attr('src', next.find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 activePic" id="img1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150 " class="imgclass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100 " class="imgclass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200 " class="imgclass">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" id="img4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150 " class="imgclass">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button id="back">&larr;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mainImg col-md-10">
      <img src="Aliens.jpg" class="bigimg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <button id="fwd">&rarr;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```